# jQuery - Unexpected Identifier with simple code

Tags: jquery

I am getting unexpected indentifier on this code:

```
(function( $ ) {
var issuccess = $issuccess;
if(issuccess == 1){

    ('.forumform').hide();   
    $('#status').html('<br /><div class='center'><img src='themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif'></div>');
}else{
    alert('error');  
}
});
```

I simply cant find the error....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
('.forumform').hide();
```

should be:

```
$('.forumform').hide();
```

In this line you have unescaped apostrophes in the string:

```
$('#status').html('<br /><div class='center'><img src='themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif'></div>');
```

Use a backslash to escape the apostrophes:

```
$('#status').html('<br /><div class=\'center\'><img src=\'themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif\'></div>');
```

Alternatively use quotation marks in the HTML:

```
$('#status').html('<br /><div class="center"><img src="themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in this line:

```
   $('#status').html('<br /><div class='center'><img src='themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif'></div>');
```

You need to espace the embedded single quote inside the string literal:

```
$('#status').html('<br /><div class=\'center\'><img src=\'themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif\'></div>');
```

Besides, you probably mean this (the dollar sign was missing in your code):

```
$('.forumform').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quoted string for html attributes.

```
(function( $ ) {
  var issuccess = $issuccess;
  if(issuccess == 1){

    $('.forumform').hide();   
    $('#status').html('<br /><div class="center"><img src="themes/steel/theme/image/blueloader.gif"></div>');
    }else{
      alert('error');  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put that html code into double quotes. and leave the single quotes inside.

```
 $('#status').html("<br /><div class='center'><img src='themes/steel/theme/images/blueloader.gif'></div>");
```

edit: just do what Guffa said! =)